# Nx, Vite, SolidJS and Tailwind: how do I configure these?

Tags: tailwind-css, vite, postcss, solid-js

I am trying to get Nx, Vite, SolidJS and Tailwind to play nicely together. I have hacked around a bit because it seems the Nx SolidJS doesn't work with the current version of Nx.

I'm not convinced my postcss config is being read. My serve target in `project.json` for my app looks like this:

```
"serve": {
  "executor": "@nrwl/vite:dev-server",
  "defaultConfiguration": "development",
  "options": {
    "buildTarget": "chonk-solidjs:build"
  },
  "configurations": {
    "development": {
      "buildTarget": "chonk-solidjs:build:development",
      "hmr": true
    },
    "production": {
      "buildTarget": "chonk-solidjs:build:production",
      "hmr": false
    }
  }
}
```

My `vite.config.ts` looks like this:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

import viteTsConfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import solidPlugin from 'vite-plugin-solid';

export default defineConfig({
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/chonk-solidjs',

  css: {
    postcss: './postcss.config.js',
  },

  build: {
    target: 'esnext',
  },

  server: {
    port: 4200,
    host: 'localhost',
    fs: {
      allow: ['..'],
    },
  },

  preview: {
    port: 4300,
    host: 'localhost',
  },

  plugins: [
    viteTsConfigPaths({
      root: '../../',
    }),
    solidPlugin(),
  ],

  // Uncomment this if you are using workers.
  // worker: {
  //  plugins: [
  //    viteTsConfigPaths({
  //      root: '../../',
  //    }),
  //  ],
  // },

  test: {
    globals: true,
    cache: {
      dir: '../../node_modules/.vitest',
    },
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
  },
});
```

My `postcss.config.js` looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {
      config: join(__dirname, 'tailwind.config.js'),
    },
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};
```

and finally my `tailwind.config.js` looks like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './index.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,css,md,mdx,html,json,scss}',
  ],
  darkMode: 'class',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        secondary: '#9E752F',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

The tailwind classes are not being applied. What additional configuration do I need?

ChatGPT seems to think I need this:

```
import postcss7compat from 'postcss7-compat';
import tailwindcss from 'tailwindcss';

module.exports = {
  purge: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
  plugins: [tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'), postcss7compat()],
};
```

...but that turned out to be nonsense.